# OPA: the HttpRequest.get_body() is not working

Tags: web-services, opa

I am testing a opa example for REST call on Mac os X 10.8.2  + OPA 1.0.7 + node.js v0.8.14.

first, I follow the example :
     https://github.com/cedricss/ian-oliver-tutorials/blob/master/tutorial4.opa

Using [ CURL -d "posted data"  localhost:8080/expressions  ] to  test post call, I found  the HttpRequest.get_body() is not working, and the server is not response,  but  the get call is working.
I commented HttpRequest.get_body() invoking, the server is working.

Then, I follow the OPA's site example:

```
  https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/Hello%2C-web-services
```

the same problems,  and  invoke  HttpRequest.get_form_data()  is not working , 
to invoke HttpRequest.getURI() is working.

I don't know where is wrong, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm, it is a bug that appears in the last versions of Opa. Thanks for the report. You can watch the thread issue on https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/issues/95